# How can I convert string to time object for calculation

Tags: c#

how do I format output in seconds:milliseconds format?

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse(pair.Value[3]);
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse(pair.Value[4]);
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.Compare( start,end));
```

The code here is printing the difference in seconds. how can i fix it using string.format as i dont know the convention for milliseconds?

Comment: The TimeSpan.Compare function doesn't return the difference in seconds. It returns -1, 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the difference between the two timespans.

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(42); // 42 ticks
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(420000000);
TimeSpan diff = end.Subtract(start);
string ms = diff.Milliseconds.ToString();
string sec = ((int)diff.TotalSeconds).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(sec + ":" + ms);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Console.WriteLine(end.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's in seconds, you could just multiply the answer by 1000 and write that out as a string?

Otherwise, take a look at this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882581.aspx